# Order of data bits

Tags: binary, boolean-algebra

In general when labelling data bits, say for a binary number. If I have four bits to represent such a number and I label them \$\ b1, b2, b3, b4 \$. Should \$\ b1\$ or \$\ b4\$ be the most significant bit? Which side do I start counting from?

Is there a general rule for this or does it rely upon specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle the agreed upon style of writing is as suggested by Gregory, we start with 0 and count up, as such representing the power-of number:

- b0 has a value of 2 to the power of 0 --> 1
- b1 has a value of 2 to the power of 1 --> 2
- b2 has a value of 2 to the power of 2 --> 4
- b3 has a value of 2 to the power of 3 --> 8

So, by convention of use the b0 would be the Least Significant Bit and b3 would be the Most Significant in a 4 bit number.

Whether those bits come first or last on a transmission medium or if the one is on the left or the right side in a data storage device, that's entirely up to the hardware and protocols used.

But it is a very general convention for a b0 to be Least Significant. Keeping that will let your developments be understood by the rest of the world.

Comment: There is also the factor that the bit numbers would change (under big endian bit numbering) if the size of the chunk/word changes (assuming *more significant* bits are appended) or two word sizes are supported. (IBM uses big endian bit numbering for Power which has 32-bit and 64-bit versions; furthermore Power's segmentation can make bit 63 of the effective address be named bit 77 of the virtual address and then that same least significant bit can be 59 in the real (i.e., physical) address. This seems suboptimal with respect to clear communication and understanding.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context.

If b1 - b4 is referring to the order in which the bits are received over a digital communication channel, the MSB and LSB must be specified and agreed upon by both sides ahead of time. There is no universal standard and neither order is more correct than the other.

However, if you're representing a binary number in writing, the convention is standardized by grammar. A binary number is still just a number. We read numbers (and words) left to write. The left-most digit is universally understood to be the most significant digit. For example, the binary representation of one-hundred twenty-eight is **10000000**. Here, the **1** would be considered the MSB.

Comment: But be careful about bigendian vs littleendian differences. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0):

And, start nubering from 0. For me it's easiest to declare that the bit number is the power of 2 that is represented by the bit.